# TLS 1.2 support for camel-ftp version 2.17.0.redhat-630262 - Java 8

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, tls1.2, camel-ftp

I was wondering if TLS 1.2 is supported by "camel-ftp" library for Java. The version used is 2.17.0.redhat-630262. Or should we upgrade the version to the latest for getting TLS 1.2 support? The Java version is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL support is provided by the underlying JDK. Java 8 has TLS V1.2, so this is available to camel -ftp (sftp endpoint).  If you set `securityProtocol` to `TLS`, you will get the TLS protocols.

You may want to ensure that only the TLS V1.2 protocols are enabled in your `jre/lib/security/java.security` file, as the older, weaker, TLS versions are enabled by default.